# Set Opportunity Stage before system validations fire

Tags: validation, standard-objects, standard-field

I have automated my opportunity stage field using a before insert and before update trigger,

The result of this trigger is that if a user selects a stage for the opportunity object it will be overwritten by the trigger before the object is saved,

Because their choice will be overwritten anyway I would like users to not have to select a stage when creating a new opportunity,

Since opportunity stage is a required field and there is a system validation in place to prevent an opportunity being saved without a stage this cannot be solved with workflows or triggers,

I would greatly appreciate a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom button and pass `&opp11=<default value>` which will assign the default stage value in the `stage` picklist.

URL will be like this: `/006/e?retURL=%2F006%2Fo&opp11=New`

Comment: I'm having some trouble overwriting the new button on the standard opportunities object, would you be able to send me in the right direction here?

Comment: Sure, let me know what issue you are facing, I am not at my desk now, I will respond that tonight

Comment: Thank you Santanu! I can't seem to make the "new" opportunity button link to a custom link, thank you for your time